# How to bypass this "unusual traffic" detection on website?

Tags: http, web-scraping, httprequest, captcha, recaptcha

For ethical reasons I would like to remark that the content of the website mentioned here is completelly offered for free, not registration needed and I'm not breaking any rule of they neither any law.

I normally develop web-scrapers for **private** usage (I mean with no economical expectations) and for one reason: it saves me a lot of time each day.

With the current site I'm scraping though, when I'm consecutively requesting 30 of their URLs, the server identifies my connection as "unusual traffic" and a Google's recaptcha appears:

[image]

I would like to know what methodology I should implement to avoid that recaptcha and still redirecting urls without problems.

The only condition is: No proxy/VPN usage.

This is what I've captured from http headers:

**Request:**

```
GET /rd/TdcfliKN0j9dT-bIMpo-GynUNR63kfnDsJn_YOP8uurTmlvy7C3oKnJtb1Mi-CI_fGsHJ72O49dM1IzXDCPNuPf3OfEb21w5hkGdV8ny__2u2pKo6yBgMbPCdAF-ti1uomfp3mWcB_K9M8PitpDMkg../x-Mad-VYWQz_lpphY5LN_fnkid__zqmI-i5AYJgziAl93kYhdvtlwVijRDmSGIifl-ouZki2eTWit7zi38raKiYkKtPqKSWftIfwFqIHD0bXua4z_LcrHQOnKwCWSNp0kJKcowVQSza8XJ88-TWJfA.. HTTP/1.1
Host    r.plixid.com
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language es-ES,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Referer http://plixid.com/2015/12/29/vinter-sleep-die-cold-winter-2015-mp3/
Cookie  __cfduid=...; PHPSESSID=...; _ga=...; _gat=1
DNT 1
Connection  keep-alive
```

**Response:**

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date    Tue, 29 Dec 2015 11:42:47 GMT
Content-Type    text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
Connection  keep-alive
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.11
Cache-Control   private, must-revalidate
Location    http://novafile.com/0ubisyq06l8s
Pragma  no-cache
Expires -1
Server  cloudflare-nginx
CF-RAY  25c53e59f4d70db7-MAD
```

What I've tried?

- Usage of random **[user-agents](http://www.vwp-online.de/ua.php?ua_type=browser)**.
- Usage of **[x-forwared-for](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For)** header with random ipv4 and proxy.
- Send the **[DNT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do_Not_Track)** header disabled (0).
- Random wait intervals to do next requests, between 3 to 10 seconds.

What I've discovered?

- Very extended non-viable wait intervals around 10 minutes, from request to request, solves the problem.
- Doing 29 consecutive requests then waiting 10 minutes to do the 30th request does not solves the problem.

Comment: It seems the site does not want robots. You are using a robot. The site detects it. Asking how to circumvent that to me seems unethical and breaking their rules.

Comment: Look, you **are** trying to break the rules here.  The captcha is there for a reason - that's the server's way of telling you that *automated scraping is something they don't want you doing*.  I think this is probably worth a close just for being blackhat...

Comment: @nvoigt and J... Thanks for comment, but the same problem can be reproduced opening/redirecting the same url 30 times in the webbrowser (tested in Firefox)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is soliciting help with blackhat activities.

Comment: @ElektroStudios Naturally, it would.  I don't see how that changes anything, however.

Comment: @J... So in your point of view I'm "violating computer security for little reason beyond maliciousness purposes"?, really?. Anyways I respect your vote of closure.

Comment: @ElektroStudios What you are doing in this question is hacking.  Stack Overflow is a site for professional (and enthusiast) programmers.  Professionals don't hack, and I don't think we need to leave helpful how-to guides on the site for anyone in the future who *may* have more malicious or devious intents.

Comment: It doesn't really matter if your purpose is malicious or not. They do not want you to use a bot, so they stop you with a captcha. Still trying to get your bot to working after the fact is ethically questionable, even if your intent is well meant.

Comment: Also, it looks like that site is an illegal music ripping site... this question should probably be closed just for linking to it.  Seems like even Google has been hit with DMCA requests to delete links to that site.

Comment: I'm not really sure about EEUU laws but I think is not illegal offer file-hosting urls because the content is not stored in their website, it is stored in the file-hosting services, but if linking the website is a problem, I edit the question, I removed it.

Comment: Anyways seems that nobody stops to think about that the problem also happens IN THE WEBBROWSER, please don't focus on botting and ethic, if the urls are redirected 30 times in the webbrowser the same problem occurs, that is a real problem with no etichal discussion, then if using a bot the problem can be solved then why not?.

Comment: @ElektroStudios I think you are completely failing to understand what the server is doing and why.  It is throttling *any* excessive use, either by IP or some other means.  If you're actually a human being, browsing and using the site, then you can just fill in the captcha and continue.  If you're not a human (ie: a bot) then you're stuck.  **That's the point** - to stop bots.  A human at its worst is not nearly as bad as a bot potentially. It's just doubly ironic that you're trying to steal bandwidth from a pirate music site... one way or another, this question needs to be closed and deleted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I still can't find a canonical *"How to write a web scraper"* Q&A, here goes: **let your code act like a human**. You have to remember that the ones building the site do not want their content scraped, so anything that makes you look like a bot can be determined and used against you.

- This means first and foremost, your user agent must act like a browser. That is properly populate the request headers like a browser would, read the entire response and act on it (if it contains HTML).
- If the response sets cookies, store those and use them in successive requests.
- If the main document links to more resources in the received document (again, if HTML), then fetch those resources as well.
- If one of the resources (either embedded in the HTML or linked from another file) is a script, you may need to execute the script. Some sites use a pingback script, some use input detection. No pingback, no mouse events: you're a bot.
- Throttle your requests intelligently. Five requests in one second is suspicious, but so is one request exactly every five seconds.

All of this is rather trivial. If you can think of it, the developer of the site (or library) has also thought of it. It's usually a matter of trial and error. There is no silver bullet, as every site can have custom code or different detection settings in the libraries they use.

That being said, and to address the moral of this story: if a site does show even the slightest reluctancy to being scraped, **don't scrape it**.

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to do something that the site does not want done. You want to do this ethically.  I suggest that you write up your case and present it directly to the site owner. I see that plixid.com has a "contact us" button (top right of the page).

People are generally reasonable. If you have a good reason for your request, and they can make the change with little effort, they are very likely to help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I really didn't tried to expose my problem with they because I think thet will ignore my needs (make changes on a website only for the needs of 1 user?, sure they think I'm stupid). But I'm gonna try it, really.